# Expand shell variable while editing command line

Tags: bash, variable, variable-substitution, readline

If I write `ls bla.*` at the prompt and then I press <kbd>=</kbd> while the cursor is still on the `bla.*` part of the command line, the list of files matching `bla.*` is printed. If I press <kbd>*</kbd>, that word is substituted for that list.

Is something similar possible with reference to variables, rather than shell glob patterns?

In other words, I'm looking for something that would print the value of `$THISVARIABLE` when I press <kbd>some_key</kbd> while the cursor is on `$THISVARIABLE` in the command line, and/or substitute it when I press <kbd>another_key</kbd>.

Important detail, I use `set editing-mode vi` in my `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may invoke the Readline function `shell-expand-line` by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd> (on my system <kbd>Meta</kbd> is <kbd>Esc</kbd>) if the `bash` shell is in Emacs editing mode.

Illustration:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If I now press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd>, the shell replaces the whole line with

```
$ echo /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

This would also expand command substitutions and would therefore potentially execute parts of the command line needed for the expansion to occur.  It also means that unfinished things like `$(` would generate a syntax error.

This does not expand shell globbing patterns.

**If you want to use this in Vi editing mode**, then you will need to explicitly bind the `shell-expand-line` function to a key sequence as it is not bound by default.  For example, to bind it to <kbd>Ctrl+e</kbd>, use

```
bind '"\C-e": shell-expand-line'
```

Using the same key sequence as in Emacs mode would obviously be problematic as <kbd>Esc</kbd> has a special function in Vi mode.